# Reading numbers in Japanese numeral-by-numeral instead of as a number

Tags: readings, numbers

I was taught that generally numbers in Japanese should be read as:

```
123 => ひゃく　にじゅう　さん
```

However, I was wonder if there is any case where the numbers are read one-by-one, like:

```
123 => いち　に　さん
```

I was thinking maybe for license plate numbers and room numbers, but I am not sure which method would be appropriate. If both are used, is there a connotation to using one pronunciation over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case is generally used for numbers representing quantity or amount like:

```
price, age, weight, distance, time
```

The second case is generally used for numbers representing identifier like:

```
phone numbers, license plate, room numbers
```

The difference between two cases is importance of number of digits, I think so.

Rarely, the second case is used for informing any numbers that is **very** important. For example, military affairs.

Answer (score 0):

Room numbers for sure, another example I thought up of is phone numbers.  Phone numbers are primarily spoken in just digits. PIN codes and the like are also spoken in just digits, sometimes people will use a word to help remember the digits. e.g. 8931 (は・く・さ・い)